# Dependency added to pom.xml causing multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

I added a new dependency (browsermob-proxy) to my `pom.xml` and apparently it contains some slf4j binding. As a result, when I execute my code it prints out the following warning messages:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/PATH/.m2/repository/net/lightbody/bmp/browsermob-proxy/2.1.4/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/PATH/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jcl/1.7.6/slf4j-jcl-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

I attempted to exclude all the dependencies that had anything to do with `slf4j` or logging from the new dependency (browsermob-proxy) like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>browsermob-proxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>

        <exclusions>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

To discover all these dependencies I just looked inside the browsermob-proxy `pom.xml`.

However doing all that didn't help and I am still getting exactly the same warnings. Am I missing something?

Comment: use `mvn dependency:tree` to see exactly what is pulled in by what.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thanks for your comment. I already did it but it doesn't look like `browsermob-proxy` is importing any dependencies. Something I probably should've added is that this whole project is a parent project of the one that I am actually executing. However I have looked at dependency trees of both of them and didn't see any errors or slf4j or logging packages imported multiple times.

Comment: After a closer look it looks like you are dealing with a copy and not a dependency.  Is there another version of the artifact you can try.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thanks again. Actually this artifact was a bit weird and I think we have manually uploaded it to company's mirror repo. Can you please elaborate what is a copy compared to dependency? Thanks!

Comment: I was guessing that you had a jar which contained all the classes referenced (a fatjar or shaded jar) but it doesn't look like it.  You should consider adding the output of  `mvn dependency:tree` to your question.

Comment: Also you should strongly reconsider removing the artifact from your local repository so you are certain you are using the same artifact as everybody else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the warn means there is a StaticLoggerBinder.class in browsermob-proxy-2.1.4.jar, not it's dependencies. But I can't find this jar in maven central repo, so can't verify that at the moment.

You'd better check the jar, and see if org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder exists

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check that. What should be done if I do find this class?

Comment: @EugeneS There is not much can be done. just delete that class manually, or report a bug to the jar provider.